# How To Reference a Variable Inside The Same Array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

```
$price = $product->price;
$priceData = [
    'subtotal' => $price,
    'tax' => $price * 0.13,
    'total' => $price + >>>> $tax <<<<
];
```

How can I get the value of `'tax'` and use it inside `'total'`?

Comment: Is the `$price` array supposed to contain itself as a value?

Comment: No, I altered this code from my project before posting. I will change the name of the array to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't perform the _$price + $tax_ calculation outside of the array first?

Comment: `$tax` is not defined but `$priceData['tax']` is

Comment: $priceData['tax'] does't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way you are trying to do it.  You have about three options:

```
$priceData['subtotal'] = $price;
$priceData['tax'] = $price * 1.13;
$priceData['total'] = $price + $priceData['tax'];
```

Or:

```
$priceData = [
    'subtotal' => $price,
    'tax' => $price * 1.13
];
$priceData['total'] = $price + $priceData['tax'];
```

Or:

```
$tax = $price * 1.13;
$priceData = [
    'subtotal' => $price,
    'tax' => $tax,
    'total' => $price + $tax
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to separate your calculations from the structure, and create the structure after the calculations.

```
$tax = $price * 1.13;
$total = $price + $tax;

$data = [
  'subtotal' => $price,
  'tax' => $tax,
  'total' => $total
];
```